# new roof + new skylight windows

Tags: windows, shingles, skylight

The roofers are installing a new roof on my house today.  Since one of the skylight windows cracked, should I get them to replace the window at the same time, or should I get one installed by a manufacturer (e.g., Pella) at a later date?

If I choose the latter, do I need to keep a few spare shingles around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all sky lights on a roof are mounted a 2x3 or 2x4 curbing that is nailed down to the roof sheathing. Flashing metal pieces are the bent up and nailed to the outside of the curbing and put down under each succeeding tier of shingles. The skylight generally us sized to fit on the top of the curbing and has a flange that comes down along the side of the outside of the curbing. The flange should come down far enough so that it fully covers the top edges of the flashing metal pieces that come up along the side.

As the roofers are already up on the roof doing work around the skylight it should be a piece of cake to have then install the new skylight. Mounting is typically as simple as nailing or screwing through holes in the side flange into the side of the curbing. Having the roofers do the job allows them to remove the old one and give then the correct access to install the new flashing metal as then shingle past the opening and curbing.

Another significant advantage is that it keeps one less person or group of persons off your roof that could do damage to your new roofing.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not bought any new skylight windows yet :(  I asked the roofers to source them but they have not gotten back to me.

If I ask a manufacturer such as Pella to install a window for me, the work should be good enough, right, since it should carry some warranty?

Comment: The factory window installers will likely do nothing except remove the old one off the curbing and plunk the new one down in its place. They will likely not be willing to vouch for the roofing or flashing. BTW You could even source the skylights yourself and the have the roofers put them on. Most big box stores or lumber/home centers will carry standard sized models in stock.

Comment: I will go to Lowes or Home Depot to try to pick up two 2' x 4' skylight windows early in the morning.  The roofers will be back for one more day only.

Comment: If the above doesn't work out, I will hire the same roofers in the spring (of 2016) to install the new skylight windows.  That way the warranty of the roof should remain intact.

@MichaelKaras: Thanks for your excellent advice!

Comment: Update: we asked the roofers to source and install the two skylight windows yesterday, who agreed to do it but warned that the existing windows are not of the modern style and form factor as they are about 25 years old.  They installed them today before laying down new shingles around them.  @MichaelKaras: thanks for your advice again.